# How to disable the editField of JxDatePicker in java

Tags: java, swing

I am designing a small desktop application in swings with Netbeans IDE and i am using JXDatePicker for fetching the dates. Is it possible to  make the editable field as non-editable by the user i.e. only a button click allow user to add date in field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the editable field as non-editable by the user
>   i

Yes!! *You can do it like this*

```
jxDatePicker.getEditor().setEditable(false);
```

- [`jxDatePicker.getEditor()`](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/0.8/docs/api/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.html#getEditor%28%29) will return the [`javax.swing.JFormattedTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) used to edit the date selection.

Comment: Thankx, it works, is it also possible to fetch and show only customised format of date in editfield